# how to add filters to servlet when using @enablewebmvc annotation in spring 4?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

Here is the current configuration

```
public class WebAppConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER_ENCODING = "UTF-8";
    private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER_NAME = "characterEncoding";
    private static final String CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER_URL_PATTERN = "/*";

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";
    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(ExampleApplicationContext.class);

        configureDispatcherServlet(servletContext, rootContext);
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
        configureCharacterEncodingFilter(servletContext, dispatcherTypes);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }

    private void configureDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext, WebApplicationContext rootContext) {
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME,
                new DispatcherServlet(rootContext)
        );
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(DISPATCHER_SERVLET_MAPPING);
    }

    private void configureCharacterEncodingFilter(ServletContext servletContext, EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes) {
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER_ENCODING);
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic characterEncoding = servletContext.addFilter(CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER_NAME, characterEncodingFilter);
        characterEncoding.addMappingForUrlPatterns(dispatcherTypes, true, CHARACTER_ENCODING_FILTER_URL_PATTERN);
    }
}
```

Now I want to use `@EnableWebMvc`

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.mvc.base.controller" })
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

how would I add `filters` and `Listeners` to servletContext which I did using `WebApplicationInitializer`?

Answer (score 0):

1. You still continue adding filters and listeners thorough your WebApplicationInitializer. This class methods starts up the web application with a Servlet registered with required contexts and beans.
2. In This class a DispatcherServlet is created containing programmatically configured AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.The dispatcher is also mapped to .html.
3. WebAppConfig class enables WebMVC based on annotation and scans the base packages for the annotated resources. These are further registered by the web application context of the default servlet which was initialized by WebApplicationInitializer.

Comment: I dont want to have to webApplicationInitiiizer and WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. I am looking at ways to combine into webMvcConfigurerAdapter